# wp_localize_script with mce_external_plugins in wordpress

Tags: plugin-tinymce

I am not sure if it is possible or not.

Can i use `wp_localize_script` with `mce_external_plugins` filter?

I want to send a variable to the tinymce plugin script. For Example:

```
add_filter( "mce_external_plugins", array( &$this, 'add_test_plugin' ) );

public function add_test_plugin( $plugin_array ){

    global $pagenow;

    if( is_admin() && $pagenow == "post.php" || $pagenow == "post-new.php" ){
        $plugin_array['mytest'] = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/testing.js';
        return $plugin_array;
    }

}
```

I have to send a variable to `testing.js`? How do i achieve this?

### Update:

this is the link that help me to resolve my problem [Using post ID in custom tinyMCE button](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121093/using-post-id-in-custom-tinymce-button#answer-121102)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly; you just need to make a Javascript variable available to testing.js.

I think it would be just as useful to send the variable with jQuery, as that would be loaded prior to TinyMCE anyway:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'YOUR_NAME_scripts'); //back end

function YOUR_NAME_scripts( $hook_suffix ) {

        global $blog_id;
        $params = array(
            'site_url' => site_url(),
            'admin_ajax_url' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            'mytest' => $whatever_variable_value


         );

            wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_VARIABLE_HOLDER', $params );

}
```

Then you can access the mytest variable in testing.js by simply using `YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_VARIABLE_HOLDER.mytest` anywhere in the script.

Comment: sorry but `wp_localize_script` is not working with `'jquery'` and it is not passed my variable to the script.

Comment: make sure when registering your script, you tell it to load jquery as a dependency. example: `wp_register_script('your-testing', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/testing.js', array('jquery') );`

Comment: as you see in my codes `$plugin_array['mytest'] = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/testing.js';` i am not registering my script. This is one way to load js for tinymce button. That's why `wp_localize_script` not working.

Comment: You should register your script the Wordpress way.  It makes life easier for everyone when we have coding standards.

Comment: then how do i merge my registered script in `$plugin_array` array?

Comment: i did another solution with the help of this thread http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121093/using-post-id-in-custom-tinymce-button#answer-121102, and this helped to achieve what i want :). And really thankful to you to continuing with me :)

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress documentation on the mce_external_plugins filter hook proposes to use two filter hooks to add your variable to testing.js:
admin_head-post.php and admin_head-post-new.php
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_external_plugins

This is the sample:

```
foreach ( array('post.php','post-new.php') as $hook ) {
     add_action( "admin_head-$hook", 'my_admin_head' );
}

/**
 * Localize Script
 */
function my_admin_head() {
    $plugin_url = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
    ?>
<!-- TinyMCE Shortcode Plugin -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var my_plugin = {
    'url': '<?php echo $plugin_url; ?>',
};
</script>
<!-- TinyMCE Shortcode Plugin -->
    <?php
}
```